# Python - How can I store data from a text file without storing all data simultaneously in the primary memory?

Tags: python, text, io, text-files

I have a text file which has an unknown number of lines. Each line is either "0" or "1".

I need to analyse the text file, for example I need to find how many 1s and 0s are in the file.

So would it be incorrect to do this?

```
fo = open("data.txt", "r")
numbers = fo.read().splitlines()
fo.close()
```

Comment: That code reads the whole file contents into a temporary string. It then splits that string into a list of strings. And then it gets rid of the temporary string. So it uses quite a bit of RAM. It's much better to iterate over your file line by line, as shown in Prashant Sethi's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to read it line by line

```
count = 0
with open("data.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        count += int(line)
```

This won't read all data at once, but one line at a time. When you use `with` you don't need to explicitly close the file, it will close automatically when the whole file has been read.

This answer assumes that the file is in the format you mentioned, that each line is either 0 or 1, and it gives number of 1s as output.

For both 0 and 1 you can use this:

```
count = {"0": 0, "1": 0}
with open("data.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        line = line.strip()
        count[line] = count.get(line) + 1
```

Comment: You should run `line` through `.strip()` to get rid of whitespace, especially trailing newlines, if you want to use it as a `dict` key. Of course, your 1st code block doesn't need that because `int()` will ignore leading & trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! I added that call now.